# Django: String format using class field

Tags: python, django

I want to upload photos to different directories. The directory name should have a *title* from a model class field. I tried this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"image/posts/{title}")
```

It created this:

[image: Upload path]

I wanted to see the post's title where I get `<django.db.models.fields.CharField>`.

How can I get the text from this field. To set the text, I used the Django admin panel.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"image/posts/{title}")
```

---

For clarification: In my image field, I set the upload address. This address is different for every post. One directory per post. The directory name should be the value of the `title` field.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]!  Please add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, I find it hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the value of `title` for the instance of Post to which you are uploading the image, `upload_to` needs to be a [callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). That callable will receive the instance as an argument and you can then get the title.

Something like this:

```
def post_image_path(instance, filename):
    title = instance.title
    return f"image/posts/{title}/{filename}"

class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_image_path)
```